# What is the difference between Clam Chowder and New England style?

Tags: soup, seafood, stews, american-cuisine

What makes clam chowder a New England style vs. some other style?

Answer (score 7):

There are several major varieties of clam chowder, which you can find enumerated on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clam_chowder). New England clam chowder is characterized by a dairy base, usually with some sort of salt pork or bacon, and potatoes.

Note:  the term chowder basically just means soup or stew, usually with seafood of some sort--very different dishes may go by the name.